# Emberjs - handlebars-actions inside CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

I got a strange Problem here. I want to catch an Action inside a rendered Ember.CollectionView, in the "ParentView".

```
{{#collection contentBinding="view.content"}}
    <a href="#" {{action insideCollection target="parentView">{{view.content}}</a>
{{/collection}}
```

but the parentView inside a CollectionView is still a Subclass of a View, and not the ParentView itself (in my Example the ApplicationView). So, how can i catch the Handlebars-Action inside my ApplicationView?

Here is a fiddle to see the Problem by yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/smgMt/3/

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `collection` helper, there is an implicit view created for each content in the block. So here, if you want to access the ApplicationView, you have to call twice parentView.

The second hint is you must prefix this chain by the keyword `view` to access the current view properties.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>Hello from Ember.js</h1>
  <button {{action test target="view"}}>Click to Test</button>
  {{#collection contentBinding="view.content" tagName="ul"}}
    <a href="#" {{action insideAction target="parentView.parentView"}}>{{view.content}}</a>
 {{/collection}}
</script>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smgMt/14/